# Доступ к серверу через роутер и nginx

Tags: nginx

Есть роутер netis n2

Роутер получает белый ip по dhcp(ipv4) от провайдера.

К роутеру подключен ноут с debian, который получает от роутера 192.168.1.109 и этот ip зарезервирован на роутере именно для этого ноута.

Так же есть домен. Допустим mysite.ru, который я купил и привязал к белому ip который получает роутер(через днс конечно же).

На роутере я сделал портфорвардинг: все http запросы на внешний порт 80 роутера перенаправляются на внутренний порт 80 ноута.

На порту 80 ноута висит nginx и слушает этот порт.

На nginx сделано проксирование на внутренний сервер с бэкендом на порту 8282. Вот полный конфиг:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        root /var/www/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        server_name mysite.ru;
        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8282/;
        }
}
```

В моем понимании, когда я перехожу в браузере по mysite.ru, то я должен попасть на сервер с бэкендом, так как перенаправление порта роутера сделано на nginx, а оттуда на сервер с бэкендом. Но проблема в том что переходя на mysite.ru я всегда попадаю в настройки роутера. Подскажите пожалуйста, что не так? Где я не ошибся?

UPD: Если ввожу в браузере 192.168.1.109 без порта или localhost без порта, то попадаю на бэкенд, что говорит о том что проксирование правильно сделано.

Comment: А если попробовать открыть через устройство, не имеющее отношения к роутеру (например через мобильный интернет)?

Comment: @andreymal тоже самое

Comment: @andreymal поправка. В этом случае 502 ошибка от nginx. Получается все таки дошло до nginx.

Comment: @andreymal почему то стало работать
Ранее не работало через мобильные данные тоже

Comment: В общем, я предполагаю, что портфорвардинг у роутера действует только на внешний интерфейс (на интернет), а для локальной сети он не действует, а так как внешний IP-адрес принадлежит роутеру, то в итоге роутер сам принимает и обрабатывает запрос, пришедший изнутри локальной сети (но так как я с конкретно этим роутером никогда не работал, это лишь неуверенное предположение)

Comment: @andreymal это похоже на правду. А из локади я могу обращаться по внутреннему ip без проблем.